# A question on a 2-group with an elementary Abelian maximal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, p-groups, maximal-subgroup

Let $G$ be 2-group of order $2^{n+1}$($n\geqslant2$) which has a maximal subgroup $N\cong\mathbb{Z}_{2}^{n}$. It is straightforward to check that if $G$ is an Abelian group, then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}^{n+1}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{4}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}^{n-1}$. But, in the case $G$ is a nonabelian group the only group I found is $D_{8}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}^{n-2}$. Is there any other possible structure for each $n$?

Comment: Let $x$ lie in $G\setminus N$, and $h\in N$. Then $C_N(x)=C_N(hx)$, so $|C_N(x)|$ does not depend on the specific choice of the element $x$. So now let $x$ act by swapping some basis elements of $N$ in pairs. This obviously can make $|C_N(x)|$ smaller than in your example.

Comment: In fact you can always choose a basis of $Z_2^n$ such that the action is to swap some pairs of the basis elements and fix the rest, so all actions arise in this way.